# JsonConvert.DeserializeObject generates a null dynamic object

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, json.net, dynamic-variables

I'm attempting to deserialize a response from a REST API using JSON.NET.

```
dynamic resultObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseText);
```

I'd like to not have to define classes for the different kinds of responses the REST API returns, as it changes often. I'd like to take advantage of `dynamic` runtime variables.

In VS2015, I've added watchers to see the values directly after the line of code above executes.

`resultObject` resolves to a null `object`, however, the watcher shows that the line code run directly results in a`Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject` which is populated with the deserialized response string.

Why doesn't the dynamic var `resultObject` populate with the `JObject`?

```
            var responseStream = e.Response?.GetResponseStream();
            string responseText = "";

            if (responseStream != null)
            {
                using (var reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                {
                    responseText = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }

                dynamic responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseText); 

                foreach (var error in responseObject["errors"].Children())
                {
                     errors.Add(error.Val);
                }

            }
```

**UPDATE:**

Contents of the JSON to parse:

JSON updated to remove debug information - problem persists.

https://jsonblob.com/57cb00c7e4b0dc55a4f2abe9

**UPDATE 2:**

It appears that `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` is parsing my JSON to have extra brackets around the entire object.

String as it is generated from the response stream:

`"{\"message\":\"422 Unprocessable Entity\",\"errors\":[[\"The email must be a valid email address.\"],[\"The password must be at least 8 characters.\"]],\"status_code\":422}"`

value of JsonConvert.DeserializeObject():

`{{
  "message": "422 Unprocessable Entity",
  "errors": [
    [
      "The email must be a valid email address."
    ],
    [
      "The password must be at least 8 characters."
    ]
  ],
  "status_code": 422
}}`

**UPDATE 3:**
Converting to `JObject.Parse` resulted in the same output.

I changed the variable from type `dynamic` to `JObject` - to accept the response from `JObject.Parse()` and still the variable is set to null.

Comment: What's the text of response? With simple json object I get properties in dynamic object just fine.

Comment: @Evk I've added the contents to the question. There is quite a bit of unnecessary debug info in the request. I'll remove that and see if that works.

Comment: @dbc Updated to remove screenshot and provide minimal, complete code sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that, in the following line, you are assuming that `"errors"` is an array of JSON **objects**, each with a property named `"Val"`:

```
foreach (var error in responseObject["errors"].Children())
{
     errors.Add(error.Val);
}
```

However, `"errors"` is actually an array of **arrays**, and so `error.Val` evaluates to `null`.  Instead you need to do something like:

```
var errors = new List<string>();

dynamic responseObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseText);

foreach (dynamic errorList in responseObject["errors"].Children())
{
    foreach (dynamic error in errorList.Children())
    {
        errors.Add((string)error);
    }
}
```

Personally, however, I recommend avoiding use of `dynamic` because you lose the advantages of static, compile-time type checking.  Code full of `dynamic` objects can also be hard to debug.  Instead I would recommend the use of [LINQ to JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm), specifically the [`SelectTokens()`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) along with the [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) recursive descent operator `..*` to pick out all string values inside the `"errors"` object like so:

```
var token = JToken.Parse(responseText);

var errors = token.SelectTokens("errors..*")    // Iterate through all descendants of the "errors" property
    .OfType<JValue>()                           // Filter those that are primitive values
    .Select(v => (string)v)                     // Convert to their string values
    .ToList();                                  // And evaluate the query as a list.
```

Example [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/gfc9sH).

Answer (score 1):

I think, JSonConvert is invalid for solve your task. You can simply use [JObject](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) and [JObject.Parse](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Parse.htm) and then iterate "errors" property by [Item](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Item_1.htm)

Comment: Migrating from `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject()` to `JObject.Parse()` concluded in the exact same result. The response from `JObject.Parse` has an extra set of braces around the object.

Comment: Even when I declare the object to be of type `JObject` it still doesn't take the assignment. Very weird!

Comment: Initializing the object to an empty `JObject`, then running `JObject.Parse()` worked - I don't think that's how it's supposed to work but it does.